# On duplicate key sets 1 column to zero on update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently experimenting `insert ignore .. on duplicate key update ..` statement in mysql. I have the following query;

`INSERT INTO user (user,password,age) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password=? AND age=?`

I have the following bindings on pdo;

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'hello' (length=7)
  1 => string 'world' (length=7)
  2 => int 24
  3 => string 'welcome' (length=7)
  4 => int 24
```

The `user` column is unique but the other columns are not. There is also auto incremented `id` field which is primary key.

However, there exists a problem. Whenever `update` function is executed, it sets the password to 0 (which is not suppose to happen)

So, what am I doing wrong here ?

NOTE: I'm using PDO library

[EDIT] : The code according to the comment;

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$exec = $statement->execute($bindings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `AND` in `password=? AND age=?` replace `and` with `,`.
Replace:

```
INSERT INTO user (user,password,age) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password=?,age=?
```

Comment: Ah, nice catch, totally missed that ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your binding a string as an integer somewhere...However, just use this:

```
 INSERT INTO user (user,password,age) VALUES (?,?,?) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password=VALUES(password), age=VALUES(age);
```

.. no need to bind the same variable/value again.